# How to make ggplot wider, when there are many bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, width

I'm using code in the reports, where a graph gets generated. The problem is that sometimes we get just a few categories - then the plot looks very nice, but sometimes many categories and then the plot become unreadable.

I want ggplot to make these graphs wider and I can't figure out how.

Does anybody know how to do that? Below is an example.

[image]

Here is a short version of the reproducible example:

```
tmp_data <- data.frame('topic_main_keyword_category' = c(paste0(c("Avoid Ticks In Dog", "Bedbugs Ticks & Fleas", "Cat & Dog Fleas Difference"), 1:55)), 
                       'topic_search_volume' = sample(seq(10, 550, 10)), 
                       'category_count' = sample(1:55))
multiplier <- max(tmp_data$topic_search_volume) / max(tmp_data$category_count)
            
ggplot(tmp_data) + geom_col(mapping = aes(x = topic_main_keyword_category, y = category_count, fill = topic_main_keyword_category)) +
                      geom_line(group = 1, mapping = aes(x = topic_main_keyword_category, y = topic_search_volume/multiplier),
                                color = 'darkorange1', size=1) + 
                      ylab('Topics count') +
                      xlab('Categories') +
                      ggtitle('Topic categories') +
                      theme_bw(base_size = text_size_on_plots) +
                      scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
                      guides(fill = "none") +
                      scale_y_continuous(
                        sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*multiplier, name = "Search volume", 
                                            labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = " ", scientific = FALSE))) +
                      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1))
```

EDIT: I wanted to make these plots automatically - meaning that they get saved as png with the proper width without the need of adjusting it manually.
In the end I made it like this (although I don't think it is an optimal solution..):

```
width <- 5 # image width
  if(length(unique(tmp_data$topic_main_keyword_category))<35) { width <- 5}
  if(length(unique(tmp_data$topic_main_keyword_category))>=35 & length(unique(tmp_data$topic_main_keyword_category))<55) { width <- 10}
  if(length(unique(tmp_data$topic_main_keyword_category))>=55 & length(unique(tmp_data$topic_main_keyword_category))<100) { width <- 15}
  if(length(unique(tmp_data$topic_main_keyword_category))>=100) { width <- 25}

  g <-  ggplot(tmp_data) +
          geom_col(mapping = aes(x = topic_main_keyword_category, y = category_count, fill = topic_main_keyword_category)) +
          geom_line(group = 1, mapping = aes(x = topic_main_keyword_category, y = topic_search_volume/multiplier),
                    color = 'darkorange1', size=1) + 
          ylab('Topics count') +
          xlab('Categories') +
          ggtitle('Topic categories') +
          theme_bw(base_size = text_size_on_plots) +
          scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
          guides(fill = "none") +
          scale_y_continuous(
            sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*multiplier, name = "Search volume", 
                                labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = " ", scientific = FALSE))) +
          theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1))
  ggsave('Topics_categories.png', plot = g, width=width)
```

Comment: (1) You can resize the view, e.g., RStudio's graphics pane, Rterm's window. If you are rendering to a file (e.g., `pdf(.)`), then the graphics-recording function (`pdf`, `png`, `jpg`, ...) should all accept dimensions. (2) Less than ideal, but perhaps it's necessary ... split this into two plots by faceting. It's better to facet (without `scales="free_y"`) than do 2+ separate plots, in order to preserve the same visual height between the facets. Faceting separates components of the plot, so may be less than ideal. (3) `plot_ly` or shiny div with scrolling "x"?

Comment: Bottom line, `ggplot2` doesn't make plots wider, it is constrained by the active canvas. If that canvas is a viewing pane, you control it literally with your mouse to resize it; if the canvas is programmatic for recording to a file, then you control it with explicit arguments (which is effectively true for shiny-based solutions as well, though plotly is its own beast in a sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to resize the plot window (e.g., clicking the "zoom" button in the plot pane in RStudio and then dragging the borders) and the save the image? This is the result I get, it seems acceptable to me:

[image]

If you want the get the image programmatically, you can save it using `ggsave` setting the `width=` option to an adequate value.